# Show $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{e^x-1}$ is divergent

Tags: integration

Im trying to show that this integral diverges:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{e^x-1}$$

the solution is:

$$\ln\left(\left|\mathrm{e}^{-x}-1\right|\right)$$
$$\rightarrow \ln(e^{-\infty}-1)-\ln(e^0-1) = \ln(-1)-\ln(0)$$

How is this divergent?

Comment: $\ln(0)$ certainly does not exist, but if you were to take limit to see the behavior near zero you would get $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \ln (x) = - \infty$ and as such the integral is divergent.

Comment: Note that the integral really means the limit of $\int_\epsilon^N\frac{dx}{e^x-1}$, as $\epsilon\to 0+$ and $N\to\infty$.

Comment: The "solution" makes no sense, since $e^{-\infty}$, $\ln(-1)$ or $\ln(0)$ have no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$The integral diverges if it diverges on $(0,1)$. **If** the integral converged on this interval, then we would have: $$\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{1}{e^x-1}\d x&=\int_0^1\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}\d x\\&=\sum_{n\ge1}\int_0^1e^{-xn}\d x\\&=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n}(1-e^{-n})\\&\overset{?}{=}\ln(1-e^{-1})+\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n}\end{align}$$But the latter sum is well known to be divergent, so the integral cannot converge. To justify the equality a bit further, if the integral converges then the series manipulations are valid; we know that the $e^{-n}/n$ series is convergent (the negative parts) so the series converges + the negative parts converges --> the positive parts converge - but since the positive part is the harmonic series, which diverges, we have a contradiction.

Comment: I think that the last inequality is in the opposite direction!

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos Thanks! I had a moment of madness. I have changed the argument now

Answer (score 1):

Set $e^{x}=y$ then the integrals is $\int_{1}^{\infty }\frac{dy}{y(y-1)}$. Take as limits $,1+\epsilon \, and\, N $ large. Then we easily obtain $-[ln|y|]_{1+\epsilon }^{N}+[ln|y-1|]_{1+\epsilon }^{N}$ Then we get $ln\frac{|N-1|}{|N|}+ln(1+\epsilon )-ln\epsilon$. The first two terms tend to $0$ and the last tends to +$\infty $ since $lim \,\epsilon$ is -$\infty$. That completes the proof!

Answer (score 0):

$e^x$ is a convex function, hence for any $x\in(0,1)$ we have $e^x-1 < (e-1)x$ and the integral cannot be convergent, since $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{e^x-1}\,dx \geq \frac{1}{e-1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x} = +\infty$.

Answer (score -1):

Prove it by comparison test.

First find the point of discontinuities. For example, we see that $0$ is a point of discontinuity.

Now consider the integral $\int_0 ^\infty \frac{dx}{x}$.

We know that the integral $\int_0 ^\infty \frac{dx}{x^n}$ converges if $n>1$, otherwise diverges. Hence, $\int_0 ^\infty \frac{dx}{x}$ diverges.

Now consider the following limit $$\text{lim}_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{e^x -1}}{\frac{1}{x}} = \text{lim}_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{e^x -1} = \text{lim}_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{e^x} = 1 \ \ \  (\text{since}\ \frac{0}{0}\ \text{form})$$

Since the limit is not equal to zero and finite, $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{e^x-1}$ diverges as $\int_0 ^\infty \frac{dx}{x}$ diverges.

Now find is there any other point of discontinuity?

Comment: Why down vote? Is my answer wrong?